# R Auto-downloaded Excel Files Loading Issue

Tags: r, excel

I auto-downloaded many of Amazon's Q-10 Reports through download.file function (mode=wb).  The downloaded files are in xls formats. When I attempt to read the xls files into RStudio with read_xls in readxl package, R mistaken some numbers for date type.  Please see the attached photo for 1) RStudio warning message 2) the reading results of R in comparison to the real data.

[Warning message from RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM2uI.png)

[RStudio vs. Real Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtciE.png)

I tried to solve the issue, and did figure out some ways to get over this, but all of them are very time-consuming:

1. If I manually convert the desired sheet to csv file, then load csv to R, everything will load correctly
2. Oddly, if I open the downloaded excel file, and save the file (without making any changes), it will pop up a message:
   [Excel Warning Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW5OY.png) After I say yes and save the file, the numbers will load correctly with read_xls.  But I would rather not click though 60+ files.

Comment: Have you got a link to the data?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer, thanks for the article.  I took "urgent" out.  This project has an approaching deadline in Mid-November.  I don't have much experience in posting questions, so I thought it would be helpful to acknowledge that.  Anyway, thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: @wl1234, the data is Amazon's 10-Q report (xls version available on Amazon investors relations website, or by this link here: https://ir.aboutamazon.com/static-files/515044e5-a52a-4eb0-bb8b-637e52008b3d) Income Statement sheet.

Comment: @wl1234, thank you for replying!

Comment: @GraceLi: I've edited it already to remove the urgency. I understand it is urgent for you, but **volunteers** here are here for curiosity and kindness, and it is inappropriate to ask them to prioritise one question over another (or, worse still, ask them to heed a deadline that does not apply to them).

Comment: In relation to adding conversational material, I sometimes offer this advice: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: @halfer, ohh I see.  Thank you again for the advice and edit!